# Wordpress posts showing in SQL database but not in Dashboard

Tags: sql, wordpress, posts

I transfered my site and I have a problem:

I cannot see any Worpdress posts that I had, and when I go inside my phpMyAdmin they are there, in wp-posts table.

All of the URLs are correct and the rest of the URL paths and everything is fine.

Does anyone have an idea how to restore that posts from SQL?

Comment: [Check this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

Comment: @JosipGvozdić Can't you see the link above?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the database connection credentials in wp-config.php? If you transferred to another host, you would most likely need to change these credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, and solved it by using the export/import tools included in WP (tools > export from old site; tools > import > install WPimporter > import on new site)

Answer (score -1):

Old issue, but just happened to me. Between dev and production.

Production had a lot of content updates, but dev had latest code, so i imported only the posts and postmeta along with taxonomy etc. The posts did not appear in wp-admin and would return 404 if accessed in frontend.

The solution was to iterate through all posts and call `wp_update_post(array('ID'=>$postID))` and it worked.